# Яким є правопис скорочення складних прикметників в тексті?

Tags: правопис, складні-прикметники

Описуючи вибагливість рослин до навколишнього середовища чи можна використовувати "скорочення" слів? Наприклад ***посухо-, морозо, вітро- та димостійка рослина***.
Чи потрібно кожне слово писати повністю ***посухостійка, морозостійка, вітростійка***?

Якщо, можна, використовувати "скорочення", то як саме правильно це написати?

Comment: чи правильно я розумію, що наявна відповідь не відповідає на питання?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ваш варіант написання вірний:

> посухо-, морозо-, вітро- та димостійка рослина

Правильно виділена стандартна частина композитних утворень -стійкість.

При цьому інтерфікс -о- лишається в першій частині перед дефісом, розділяти перелік треба комами, як будь-які однорідні члени речення, останній однорідний член пишеться згідно правопису складених слів, тобто разом.

Цікава стаття на тему:

[Граматична структура екологічних термінів у посібниках і підручниках для студентів-екологів / Лариса Тиха // Вісник Нац. ун-ту «Львівська політехніка». Серія «Проблеми української термінології». – 2012. – № 733. – С. 158–160.](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:e2BMXp256t4J:tc.terminology.lp.edu.ua/TK_Wisnyk733/TK_wisnyk733_3_tykha.htm)